# Efficiency of using multiprocessing in a single processsor

Tags: python, performance, multiprocessing

I plan to write a Python program using Python's `multiprocessing`.  The program is to run on a 4-core machine. The core calculation of the program looks like this:

```
for i in range(1000):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)
    p.start()
```

in which worker() refers to a time-consuming procedure.

## Question

In theory, will the using of multiprocessing slow down the whole program compared with the sequential version?

```
for i in range(1000):
   worker()
```

Thanks.

Comment: YES. YES YES, the way you are trying to do it. NO, depends how havy the workload of your `worker()`and you got all 4 `≠cores` to run.

Comment: You really don't want to be spawning all of those processes. Generally people keep it one core below the CPU max. There's not a lot of info given here; perhaps you would benefit from a [`Pool`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers)? It might require some refactoring of your current code base to implement.

Comment: Thank you. Your comments are very helpful.